# HELP BITCOIN SENT CONFIRMED BUT I NEVER RECIEVED BEEN 2 DAYS

Tags: lost-transactions

help im not sure what to do i sent from Pax, bitcoin like i have done many times and it shows up as confirmed, but yet i dont see it at all heres the id 7581e42bf71df4b81fdb233542f3e0baeddeb60bd5e11361b1f8cb7ccb3553a5

is anyone able to help me recover this? or is it gone for good?

Comment: What do you mean "I don't see it"?  Where do you not see it?

Answer (score 2):

> BITCOIN SENT CONFIRMED BUT I NEVER RECIEVED BEEN 2 DAYS

In reality Bitcoins are not actually sent or received. Those are not two separate events. They both really refer to the same event. If the Blockchain shows unspent bitcoins (unspent transaction outputs) associated with an address you control, you have "received" them - regardless of what your wallet says. This is easily checked using a [blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer)

> heres the id 7581e42bf71df4b81fdb233542f3e0baeddeb60bd5e11361b1f8cb7ccb3553a5

That transaction currently has 450 confirmations. It also has 12 inputs and 52 outputs. Presumably Pax have batched up their customer transactions and one of those 52 outputs is an address you gave to "Pax" (Paxful.com?).

If that address was generated by a desktop or mobile wallet, it's failure to show the amount expected could be due to a number of reasons - for example maybe it isn't fully synchronised for some reason?

> is anyone able to help me recover this?

Only the person or organisation who has the private keys from which the relevant output "address" was generated. Normally that would be you alone.

It may be that this isn't a question of "recovery" in the sense of recovering money transmitted somewhere. Perhaps you just need help finding out why your wallet doesn't show the expected amount associated with the relevant receiving address you gave "Pax". That would be a different question and depends on what wallet you use.

> is it gone for good?

The transaction is final. If you know who "received" the output in question, you can ask them for help. You could start with "Pax"